# updating text file contents using vba statement or code

Tags: vba

I have a question regarding Text file update through VBA code.

Please see the format of my text file.

No               FirstName      LastName   JoinDate 
0001             Anil           Patel      01011901 
0002             David          Sam        01121973
0003             Jaya           Shah       01011890

My question is I want to update Join date 01011901 and 01011890 to update 01012001. We have so many big text files and many dates that we have to update manually.

So if anyone helps to solve this problem it reduces our manual task.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please read the help text especially the sections on how to ask a question. SO is a question and answer site, not a free coding service. Your 'question' will almost certainly be closed, as not meeting the requirements of the site.

Comment: If the texts is greather than 1 MM Records, is better to update with another tool (Notepad ++, or Powershell commands).

If it is smaller than 500k records, so you can import to excel and make the replace using CTRL+H or looping trought vba

Comment: Hello Friends, Thanks for your comment. Can you please close this question. I have found my question solution. I have developed VBA code for it and it's working fine for me. Thank you very much for looking my question.